# CMake does not find VS 2017 C++ compiler after installation of VS 2019

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2017 Professional installed as well as Visual Studio 2019 Professional.

Because of some project restrictions I cannot control, I have to use the VS 2017 Compiler to compile the code. Before the installation of Visual Studio 2019 the following CMake command was just working fine:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

But after installation of VS 2019, above line gives the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

The last line means something like "The systen cannot find the given file".

Can anyone help me solve the problem? Sadly, as of now, I have to use the compiler from VS2017 for this particular project.

**Edit:** As suggested by Neil in the comments, using the Developer Command Prompt works just fine. Is there any way to use the Windows command prompt? It's just easier to use.

**Edit2:** I now use the solution suggested by Neil and run the commands needed in Visual Studio Command Prompt, as I could not figure out how to do it correctly in Windows command prompt.

Comment: If you run this somewhere like a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017", the path problem might be fixed

Comment: @Neil thanks, you're right, using the Developer Command Prompt solves the problem. Didn't know it even exists. Any way to solve it using the "normal" Windows terminal? If not, it's not too bad.

Comment: Look at the path in that VS2017 command prompt, find the difference between it and your normal terminal (relating to VS) and make the appropriate changes to you path in your perferred environment.  Or find those diffs and hard code them into your CMake?  Viel gluck!

Comment: BTW, what CMake version are you using?

Comment: @vre I have CMake 3.11.3 installed.

Comment: IIRC, you'll need at least CMake 3.14 for VS 2019 support. Maybe this thread is of any help? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/399774/visual-studio-2019-preview-1-running-cmake-on-comm.html

Comment: @vre: I don't need VS 2019 support in this project, the problem was that VS 2017 could not be found anymore with VS 2019 installed alongside. Using Neil's suggestion (use Visual Studio Command prompt) works just fine.

Comment: CMake always tries to find the most recent version of Visual Studio. Therefore older releases of CMake before 3.14 may fail if VS2019 is installed and not properly detected. Can you try to repeat the procedure with a more recent version of CMake and report back? Please note that you need to delete CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles folder from your build directory. If you intend to use VS2019 with CMake you need to call it with the architecture switch of CMake, e.g. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64` or `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32`

Comment: @vre: Alright, in this case I misunderstood you. My bad. I'll try and report back.

Comment: @vre: You were right, now it's working. Sadly, the "build environment" (missused conan) ships its own cmake in version 3.13. So I'll contact the responsible person. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake always tries to find the most recent version of Visual Studio. Therefore older releases of CMake before 3.14 may fail if VS2019 is installed and not properly detected.

Please note that you need to delete CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles folder from your build directory if rerunning.

If you intend to use VS2019 with CMake you need to use the architecture option (`-A`)  of CMake as there is no "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64" generator, e.g. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64` for a 64-bit build or `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32` for a 32-bit build. The architecture option was introduced in CMake 3.0.2, so you can use that instead of the specific generator name for older Visual Studio installations too.